Supernatural manhwa in which the main character drowns and later starts to see ghosts, but pretends he can't
I'm looking for a manhwa that is like Weird And Hard To Kill in which the main character drowns and later starts to see ghosts, but pretends he can't. The deeper he goes, the worse it gets.

Since you mention it being like the other book, how is it different?
